# How to call JQuery after all assets load AND canvas has fully rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am making a game which has many graphics and assets.

Thus, I created a simple loading page to show the user while it loads. I used the JQuery below to make the loading screen fade out the moment everything loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loading").fadeOut("slow")
})
```

From what I know, this should only fade out the loading screen AFTER the document has loaded completely, together with all the assets, but this is not the case! Observe the demo on the page itself: tdat.tk

As you can see, the loading screen fades out, but then the canvas is still blank and rendering. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: `canvas` is not part of things which are considered to be `loaded` in `$(document).ready`

Comment: Which is exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: If you are loading `images` over `canvas`, hide loader after `ocntext.drawImage`

Answer (score 0):

try **load()** function

```
$(document).load(function(){
    $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

load function will run only when all resources of documents will be loaded .
while ready function will run when the html of the document will be loaded  .

Comment: well in that case you need to use canvas event handler  try this     `$(document).on( "CanvasOnLoad", canvasOnLoadHandler );                 function canvasOnLoadHandler(){                 $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");   }`

Answer (score 0):

In document.ready, start your loading animation and behind the scenes load your assets. Create an array for your assets and start loading them one by one. For e.g

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  //when image loaded
};

image.src = url;
```

Once you have all the assets loaded, fadeout your loading screen. You can also refer this example http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/